# Using table cell value for javascript not <td class>

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-table

I have following table test data which is filtered using checkboxes. I want the `<script>` to use the value in each `<td>` and not the `<td class>` in order to show/hide rows based on the checkbox selections.

Is this possible by amending my current script in a simple way? it would make it a lot easier using the data I have to simple use the values rather than having to manually change the class as I add rows?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" />Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />Variable
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t4" id="t4" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<section id="fee">
  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<br>

<div id="mortgagediv">
  <table id="mortgagetable">
    <tr class="productheader">
      <th class="lender">Lender</th>
      <th class="type">Type</th>
      <th class="inititalmths">Initital Term (mths)</th>
      <th class="inititalrate">Initial Rate (%)</th>
      <th class="svr">SVR (%)</th>
      <th class="apr">Overall APR (%)</th>
      <th class="fee">Fee (£)</th>
      <th class="ltv">LTV (%)</th>
      <th class="minamount">Min Amount (£)</th>
      <th class="maxamount">Max Amount (£)</th>
      <th class="repayment">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
      <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
      <td class="f1 f3"></td>
      <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
      <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
      <td class="f1 f3"></td>
      <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
      <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
      <td class="f1 f3"></td>
      <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
      <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
      <td class="f2 f3"></td>
      <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
      <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
      <td class="f2 f3"></td>
      <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
      <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
      <td class="f2 f3"></td>
      <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
      <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best way is to use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp): just add `data-value="the value"` or whatever you want to call it. To fix your `JS` code simply change this

```
$("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
```

by this

```
$("[data-type='" + $(this).val() + '"').parent().show();
```

The other way would be to use `:contains`, [here](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) you can find how to use it. The problem with this solution is that it matches substrings, which could not be the desired behavior and can lead to incorrect results.

Comment: do I need to add the `data-value="the value"` to each `<td>` tag? Sorry if I have misunderstood? I have changed the .js, but it is not working now?

Comment: yes you should, you could just replace `class` by `data-value`. if the value you're setting in the `data-value` attributes is the inner text of your `<td>`, remember to also update the values of your checkboxes.

Comment: I don't really see the benefit of this. Is the script not just using the `data-value="the value"` and still not the actual cell contents?

Comment: If you actually **need** to use the actual contents of the cells as a filter (which I don't think is good at all) you could use what I suggested in the last paragraph of my answer, which is the `:contains` filter from `jQuery`. The problem with that, again, is that it matches substrings which can lead to unexpected behavior. IMHO you shouldn't use the values of the cells, I'd go with `data-*` attributes, which are meant for that purpose: add additional data to the DOM elements.